# Creating _analyzer mapping to use document field mapping using NEST (elastic search)

Tags: mapping, elasticsearch, analyzer, nest

How to create a _analyzer mapping using NEST client API for elastic search to allow document field property as analyzer as in ES documentation here:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/analyzer-field/

Thanks in advance. I might have missed this in
NEST documentation.

Answer (score 2):

The mapping documentation on http://nest.azurewebsites.net is a bit behind.

Have a look at this unit test: https://github.com/Mpdreamz/NEST/blob/master/src/Nest.Tests.Unit/Core/Map/FluentMappingFullExampleTests.cs

For a full example of the mapping API.

Comment: I think link is moved and now [this is the right address](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-net/blob/459ea5028865956f2a7686758a1052f8cdb32d7c/src/Nest.Tests.Integration/Core/Map/AnalyzerField/AnalyzerFieldTests.cs)

Comment: [AnalyzerFieldTests for NEST 1.4.3](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/1.4.3/src/Tests/Nest.Tests.Integration/Core/Map/AnalyzerField/AnalyzerFieldTests.cs)